# why my definition of a function that returns the pointer to another function doesn't work?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am learning pointer to functions, and want to define a function that has the return value which is the pointer to another function. In my sample program `fun` is trying to return a pointer that points to `next`. However, the program fails to compile. I have written my thought in the comment, any idea where is the problem?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int next(int );

//define next_fp as a pointer to a function that takes an int and return an int
typedef int (*next_fp)(int);

//define a function that returns a pointer to a function that takes an int and return an int
next_fp fun(next);

int main()
{

    cout << fun(next)(5) <<endl;
    return 0;

}

int next(int n) {
    return n+1;
}

next_fp fun(next)   {
    //fun's return type is next_fp, which is a pointer to
    //a function that take an int and return an int.
    return next;
}
```

Comment: There are other major _problems_ which, I hope, someone will address in a proper answer but note that your fun() function parameter has the same name of the next() function. Guess which one the compiler is picking. Now let's check what's the type of that parameter...does it match? Is it an int or a function pointer? If you wish to use C++ (or modern C, BTW) do NOT use "default int" parameters. It's a source of endless bugs and confusion.

Comment: Please always leave a [MCVE] that reproduces the problem, and include the error messages verbatim. _"Why xy doesn't work"_ is too vague and not useful for further research. Thank you.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Is there any more minimal of this version?

Comment: What about calling a function after returning from `main`?

Comment: @Albjenow It's a typo.

Comment: @buzhidao You missed to provide the exact error messages. Thitat's the point.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ However I think the error messages are too messy to put into the questions.

Comment: @buzhidao I don't consider [3 lines](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/019d6d74117eafcc) of error messages _too messy_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think you are right

Comment: Define **fails to compile**  What do you mean exactly? does it show an error? did you see it? are you hidding the error text for something?  How do you want us to help if you hide information explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
next_fp fun(next);
```

When declaring a function, you must declare the type of the arguments. Try:

```
next_fp fun(next_fp next);

// ...

next_fp fun(next_fp next) {
    // ...
}
```

As stated in the comments, you should avoid using for a parameter a name already used in the same scope for a function. You may add a trailing `_` to mark function parameters (my personal convention, feel free to use yours):

```
next_fp fun(next_fp next_);
```

Comment: using a different name for the declaration of a function and definition of a function is merely for the sake of avoiding confusion?

Comment: Yes, the compiler should consider local variables before searching further, but a human may prefer to have different names here (I would prefer ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Parameter is not declared properly in function declaration `next_fp fun(next);` (and definition);  `next` is not a type, it's a name of function.

You should change it to:

```
next_fp fun(next_fp);
```

and for definition:

```
next_fp fun(next_fp next) {
    //fun's return type is next_fp, which is a pointer to
    //a function that take an int and return an int.
    return next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int next(int );

//define next_fp as a pointer to a function that takes an int and return an int
typedef int (*next_fp)(int);

//define a function that returns a pointer to a function that takes an int and return an int
next_fp fun(next_fp);

int main()
{
    return 0;
    cout << (fun(next))(5) <<endl;
}

int next(int n) {
    return n+1;
}

next_fp fun(next_fp www)   {
    //fun's return type is next_fp, which is a pointer to
    //a function that take an int and return an int.
    return www;
}
```

Comment: This lacks explanation